# Finding a node by that doesn't have specific parent via XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to find node with name 'lbl' that have text value '10', and its parent **is not** a node with name 'Item'

```
<XML>
  <Cat>
    <Summary>
      <Item>
        <lbl>10</lbl>
    </Item>
    </Summary>        
  </Cat>  
</XML>
```

This is my xpath:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//lbl[text()='10']//not[parent::Item]")
```

But it returns a node, expected result not to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was close. The correct one will be

```
//lbl[text()='10' and not(parent::Item)]
```